# Admin -> Run Updates, Unresolved dependency

Tags: 7

When I click **Run Updates** from admin, I got som Unresolved dependency errors.  It told me File Entity (Version >7.x-2.0 required), but I'm using 2.0-beta3, as the next line stated.

**file_entity.info** is found in `sites/all/modules/file_entity/file_entity.info`

So what am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> So what am I missing?

Nothing at all, the messages are pretty clear:

The version of CKEditor Media Browser that you're updating to has a dependency on File Entity 7.x-2.0 or greater. You have version 7.x-2.0-beta3, which is not greater than 7.x-2.0, so the upgrade isn't possible.

You need to update File Entity to the required version first, then proceed with the update of the media browser module.

Do bear in mind that the modules you're dealing with are in beta, and haven't had development effort in a while. It's entirely possible that you might not be able to perform the update. Case in point: https://www.drupal.org/node/2838674

Comment: For a Drupal 7 module, the first digit of its version should be 7. I have never seen Drupal showing a version like 2.0-beta3. Quite interesting, the latest Drupal 8 version of https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity is 8.x-2.0-beta4.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I just copy-pasted form the question, it's actually 7.x-2.0-beta3: https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity/releases/7.x-2.0-beta3

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, the screenshot. Yeah that is a bit odd

Comment: Since Drupal 8 uses a different format for the .info file, Drupal 7 would not probably understand when a module is for Drupal 8, from its .info file. I wonder what would happen in that case, and what version would Drupal core report. You are correct that 7.x-2.0-beta3 is considered lower than 7.x-2.0, despite that being not intuitive. Investigating a bit on why Drupal shows a version like 2.0-beta3 would make this answer more complete.

Comment: That's beyond the scope of what's being asked @kiamlaluno, would make a good separate question perhaps

Comment: Well, the question is "Why am I getting this error message about the version of the module?" and if it happens because the OP copied the Drupal 8 version of the module, that would be the answer.

Comment: It's just formatting @kiamlaluno, see `drupal_check_incompatibility()` and its use of `version_compare()`

Answer (score 0):

The error message could be confusing, since it shows the required version without stripping out the Drupal compatibility part, and the installed version after stripping out the Drupal compatibility part.

The error message you are seeing is produced from this code.

```
    $required_file = $files[$required_module];
    $required_name = $required_file->info['name'];
    $version = str_replace(DRUPAL_CORE_COMPATIBILITY . '-', '', $required_file->info['version']);
    $compatibility = drupal_check_incompatibility($requirement, $version);
    if ($compatibility) {
      $compatibility = rtrim(substr($compatibility, 2), ')');
      $requirements["{<span class="php-variable">$module</span>}-{<span class="php-variable">$required_module</span>}"] = array(
        'title' => $t('Unresolved dependency'),
        'description' => $t('@name requires this module and version. Currently using @required_name version @version', array(
          '@name' => $name,
          '@required_name' => $required_name,
          '@version' => $version,
        )),
        'value' => t('@required_name (Version @compatibility required)', array(
          '@required_name' => $required_name,
          '@compatibility' => $compatibility,
        )),
        'severity' => REQUIREMENT_ERROR,
      );
      continue;
    }
```

As you see, `$version` is set to the value returned from `str_replace(DRUPAL_CORE_COMPATIBILITY . '-', '', $required_file->info['version'])`.

So, the error message is really saying that a version higher than 7.x-2.0 is required, but the installed version is 7.x-2.0-beta3. That is how [`version_compare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php), used from [`drupal_check_incompatibility()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_check_incompatibility/7.x) works, for which the following relation between versions is true.

```
7.x-2.x-dev < 7.x-2.0-alpha12 < 7.x-2.0-beta1 < 7.x-2.0-rc1 < 7.x-2.0
```

This could be confusing, but it makes sense if you think that version 7.x-2.0-beta1 is released (for example) before version 7.x-2.0-rc1, which is released before version 7.x-2.0 (the stable release).